# What are the rights of single permit holders for non-eu citizens

Tags: working-visas, resident-permit, working, non-citizens, bulgaria

I've been working for a company in Bulgaria and coming from a non-EU member country. As you can guess, my company provided sponsorship for the Single Permit (resident and work).

The question is: If the company does not want to work with me anymore in the future, am I going to be able to change my job? What are the regulations for this situation?

Comment: I've edited the tags because this will be controlled by Bulgarian law; there's no EU-wide legislation (unless you have a blue card -- do you?).

Comment: Thanks for the editing. I am only holding a single permit.